# Which distro support ReiserFS out of the box?

Tags: linux, bsd, reiserfs

I need an OS distro (Linux, BSD ,or any other open source) which out of the box give option to use ReiserFS for the file system

Comment: All of the good ones.  You'd be nuts to use it though.

Comment: Why? Anyone needs a killer file system!

Comment: Google can answer this question as well as Server Fault can. We're not a good place to get a "list-of-things" answer...

Answer (score 4):

List:

- OpenSuse
- Slackware
- Kubuntu
- Ubuntu
- Debian
- CRUX
- Linux Mint
- Arch Linux
- Joli OS
- ...

Source: [Link](http://www.google.be/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=distrowatch.com+ReiserFS&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=m955TcGuBdGKswbh8oHrBw#sclient=psy&hl=nl&client=safari&rls=en&q=ReiserFS+inurl:distrowatch.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d7fd154072b4cf03)

Little side note: Development of ReiserFS has stopped since the main developer was sentenced to prison. So you might want to reconsider using it on anything important.

Answer (score 3):

Hans Reiser was convicted in 2008 of murdering his wife.

Reiserfs was unmaintained for years before that.

He was working on Reiser4, but this died in 2008.

SuSE stopped supporting Reiser soon after.
SuSE was the only major OS which used Reiser by default.

If you need an FS which supports tiny files, try pgfs (postgres -> FUSE).

If you need an FS for Linux which is generally fast, try ext4.

If you need an "industrial" FS, try XFS.

Answer (score 1):

[Debain](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=debian) and [Slackware](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=slackware) both support ReiserFS out of the box. I would suspect Debian derivatives also support Reiser.

You can quickly check using distrowatch.com